# Understanding .gitignore and build directory

Tags: git, heroku

Probably a stupid question but I've confused myself over the role of .gitignore

I've completed my Angularjs app and I have created a `build` directory. I'm ready to push to Heroku but I've read that `build` directories should not be under version control so I've add the folder to my .gitignore

Therefore, my question is when I run `git push heroku master` to get the files to Heroku will it only push the files under version control or all the files? My understanding is that the build directory won't be pushed and if this is the case, how am I supposed to get it to Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will it only push the files under version control or all the files?

Only the files under version control.

> My understanding is that the build directory won't be pushed and if this is the case, how am I supposed to get it to Heroku?

See "[Deploying code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code)": the build will be done on the heroku server, using [one of the buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks).

Comment: I use gruntjs to build so are you saying I have to do this server side?

Comment: @tommyd456 yes, you can customize the build process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process

Comment: Never heard of buildpacks before! Just found this which looks useful: https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt

Comment: @tommyd456 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process

Answer (score 1):

When you use `git push heroku master` it is the same command as `git push origin master`. Only the origin URL is different.
Therefore the behavior is the same as a classic `git push`, only the files under version control will be pushed.

You will need to refer to the build system of your project to build it. For instance with Node, `npm install --production` is run on each build ([see](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support)).
So if you add for instance `bower install` in the post install of your package.json you will have a full build

Comment: and I can do this with gruntjs can I?

Comment: yes the postinstall may be more complex like `"postinstall": "bower install && grunt build"`. You may refer to this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process